# Cálculo entre transición y transversión para dos secuencias con python

Tags: python, zip

Escribí el siguiente código para calcular la relación entre transiciones y transversiones, es decir, la división entre el total de transiciones y el total de transversiones que ocurren en dos cadenas (cuando se cambia una letra por otra, según el caso).

```
transition = {'A':'G', 'G':'A', 'T':'C', 'C':'T'}

transversion = {'A':('T','C'), 'G':('T','C'), 'T':('A','G'), 'C':('A','G')}

def rel_trans(s1, s2):
    x = 0
    y = 0
   for i,j in zip(s1, s2):
       if transition[i] == j:
          x += 1 
       elif j in transversion[i]:
          y += 1
   return (x/y)

s1 = 'GCAACGCACAACGAAAACCCTTAGGGACTGGATTATTTCGTGATCGTTGTAGTTATTGGAAGTACGGGCATCAACCCAGTT'
s2 = 'TTATCTGACAAAGAAAGCCGTCAACGGCTGGATAATTTCGCGATCGTGCTGGTTACTGGCGGTACGAGTGTTCCTTTGGGT'

print(rel_trans(s1, s2))
```

El problema es que este código solo funciona en cadenas de una línea, pero cuando intento ejecutarlo en una de varias líneas, arroja un error. Es decir, quiero que me funcione en lo siguiente:

```
s1 = """TTTTGTCATTTTGCCTCGTCGTCAGGAATATTGGGACGAATTGGACTCTACT
TCTGTGGGCTGAGCCGGTTCACCCATTGACGAGTGCTAGTCACAGATGAATTACAATGAA
TTGATTTATG"""

s2 = """CCTTGTAAGTACGCGTAGCCTCCAGGAACTTTTAGGCGAATTGTACGTCACC
TCCGGGAGCCGGGCCGGTTGATCCTTTGACAAGTCCTCACAGATGTGTCACAACCAA
TTGATCTG"""
```

¿Podría alguien decirme qué debo modificar? parece que zip es el problema.

Comment: Añade `s1="".join(s1.split())` para eliminar espacios, retornos de carro y tabuladores que pudiera haber dentro de `s1` (y lo mismo para `s2`)

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que un string como

```
s2 = """C
        C"""
```

contiene retornos de carro ('\n'), lo que desincroniza todo.

Solución: filtrar los strings recibidos para eliminar todo lo que no sea una base (A, C, G, T), usando comprensión de listas:

```
ss1 = [x for x in s1 if x in "GTCA"]
ss2 = [x for x in s2 if x in "GTCA"]
```

#### Demo

```
transition = {'A':'G', 'G':'A', 'T':'C', 'C':'T'}
transversion = {'A':('T','C'), 'G':('T','C'), 'T':('A','G'), 'C':('A','G')}

def rel_trans(s1, s2):
    x = 0
    y = 0

    ss1 = [x for x in s1 if x in "GTCA"]
    ss2 = [x for x in s2 if x in "GTCA"]
    for i, j in zip(ss1, ss2):
        if transition[i] == j:
            x += 1
        elif j in transversion[i]:
            y += 1
    return x / y


s1 = """TTTTGTCATTTTGCCTCGTCGTCAGGAATATTGGGACGAATTGGACTCTACT
TCTGTGGGCTGAGCCGGTTCACCCATTGACGAGTGCTAGTCACAGATGAATTACAATGAA
TTGATTTATG"""

s2 = """CCTTGTAAGTACGCGTAGCCTCCAGGAACTTTTAGGCGAATTGTACGTCACC
TCCGGGAGCCGGGCC"""

print(rel_trans(s1, s2))
```

produce:

```
1.3636363636363635

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias. Correjí el segundo string, que no es de la misma longitud y donde me causa el problema.